# ajax call from dynamic url through jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

```
jsp file        
<td><a id="delete" href="delete?id=${user.id}">Delete</a></td>
  <div id="result"></div>
ajax call
$('#delete').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
            url : $(event.target).attr("href"),
            success : function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });

});

spring controller class with delete method
 @RequestMapping(  value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public @ResponseBody
        String deleteUser(@RequestParam int id) {
          System.out.println("Entered deleteUser");
            dataService.deleteRow(id);
            return "deleted "+id;
      }
```

Here i am trying to delete a record from jsp by calling delete user method using jquery ajax,but after deleting its going to new page with url /delete?id=180(id based on record id) instead it should delete in the same page ,how can i delete a record and display all records at the same process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML page**

```
<div id="data">
</div>
<a class="linkDelete" userid = "1" href="#">Delete</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".linkDelete").click(function(){
        var userid = $(this).attr("userid");
        var url = "www.example.com?id=" + userid;
        alert(url);

        $.get( "/delete", function( data ) {
              alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });
    });
});
```

In case you need https://jsfiddle.net/r47fbt28/

Answer (score 0):

Why you have a `href` attribute for `<a>` element when you are doing a Ajax call ?

```
<td><a id="delete" href="delete?id=${user.id}">Delete</a></td>
```

Just edit that to

```
<td><a id="delete" href="#" >Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: dn how i will pass user id to my method?

Comment: @saurabh Just google, [how to pass query parameter in ajax](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20pass%20query%20parameter%20in%20ajax)

Comment: @saurabh create another attribute in your `<a userid="{$user.id}">Delete</a>` and read `userid`

Comment: Me or @VickyThakor , neither of us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: @VickyThakor That works as a request parameter ? No, as far as I know.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yeah. He need to read value of `userid` and construct `url` in function.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ i googled but coudn't understand how to jsp el parameters ,normal parameter i know how to pass

Comment: @saurabh Can't help you further ..look at examples.